# Android & Admob unexpected data storage and cache values

Tags: android

after adding adMob ads to my application, I have noticed some strange memory behaviour. On my android phone, If I go `Settings>Applications>Manage applications>myApp` 
I obtain the storage information for my app.

What concerned me was that the Data storage was around 600kb, and the Cache was over 2.5MB (as opposed to 28kb and 0kb maximum without admob). 
After some trial and error, I discovered that the Data storage value seems to increase with the cache. If I clear the cache and restart my app, the data value drops significantly, back to what I would expect for my program.

I have no idea what this cache is doing, but it is related to adMob. I have not integrated any specific cache management in my program. I worry that if this cache content grows as it has been, then the users of my app will not be impressed if my App starts taking up 10+MB of space. Should I be worried? Could it be that because I did nothing than run my app repeatedly for a day that no other app or program will have outed my data from the cache? Should I manually clear the cache? what is it's purpose with regards to Admob?

Comment: Admob is just caching its ads so they load quicker. The Android OS will clear the /cache directory if the filesystem gets too full, and Admob *should* be managing its own cache size. You shouldn't have to worry about it

Comment: Thanks Smith I would accept this as an answer if you like

Comment: I posted it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admob is just caching its ads so they load quicker. The Android OS will clear the /cache directory if the filesystem gets too full, and Admob should be managing its own cache size. You shouldn't have to worry about it

Comment: i have same problem. now i have about 1.07 mb cache.

Comment: android wont clear the cache directory automatically never... each library shall do that

Answer (score 0):

when use the admob,it save some file(cookies,index etc) under Android/yourfile/app_webview. if you dont want increase your data usage, you can delete the file before exit your app.